# Curiosity's drive wheel motors' manufacturer?

Tags: mars, rovers

Although there are answers listed elsewhere on this site about the power requirements for the Curiosity Rover drive wheels, does anyone know what company provided those drive motors?

Comment: related: [Mars curiosity rover's Maxon drive motors](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19076/12102) and [Electric motor design for Martian environment](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25282/12102) and [The types of motors used on the Martian rovers?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12984/12102)