# What are the power specifications for Curiosity's 6 driving motors and the voltages of the two batteries, and what are the sources?

Tags: power, curiosity, battery

To calculate the maximum travel time for Curiosity without recharging its batteries, I would like to know the power specifications for its driving motors.
And we need to know how much energy can be stored in the two rechargeable batteries, but [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity_(rover)#Specifications) tells us only that they each have a capacity of 42 ampere-hours, no voltage !

What are the sources for those specifications ?

Comment: different but related and possibly helpful: [Mars curiosity rover's Maxon drive motors](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19076/12102) and [Curiosity's drive wheel motors' manufacturer?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40871/12102) and [The types of motors used on the Martian rovers?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12984/12102) and [Electric motor design for Martian environment](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25282/12102)

Comment: @uhoh  Thank you for the links. It appears that Mark Adler is the expert on this topic, but even he didn't know  the motor ratings for Curiosity.

Comment: okay great! (cleanup)